# Recursive shunting yard algorithm

Tags: algorithm, recursion, sml

everybody

I am trying to implement simple algorithm "**Shunting yard**" (**to parse infix to postfix notation**) using **SML** (**Standart ML**)

```
fun parseToRPN(input:string) = 
    let
        val _input =  explode input
        val digits = [#"0", #"1", #"2", #"3", #"4", #"5", #"6", #"7", #"8", #"9"]
        val stack = []
        val output = []
        exception Empty

        fun member(n:char, nil) = false
        | member(n:char, h::t) = if n = h then true else member(n:char, t);

        fun parse(nil) = raise Empty
        | parse(h::t) = if member(h, digits) then h::parse(t) 
                        else if h = #"(" then   ???                 
    in
    ...
    end
```

But I have no idea how to push to stack in SML.
Can somebody give some tips!
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stack is passed as an additional argument to `parse`. You'll want to pass the accumulated RPN as well.

Although the shunting-yard algorithm is usually presented as an algorithm for converting infix to postfix notation, it is actually just a parsing algorithm; you can directly evaluate infix expressions or create parse trees from them instead of doing the infix→postfix. If you choose to do the latter, then you can use a single stack, which is a stack of partial parse trees (a forest, in other words); at the end of the algorithm, if the input was syntactically correct, the stack will consist of a single parse tree which can be returned.